# Remove url param javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I need to make this url

http://test.com/deal/134487/some-deal-id?sourceType=by_category&somestring=true&anotherparam=true

Look like this

http://test.com/deal/134487/some-deal-id?somestring=true&anotherparam=true

I want to only remove the sourceType and leave everything else

This is what I have so far that seems to work great when the url is 
http://test.com/deal/134487/some-deal-id?sourceType=by_category
but as any more keys are added after sourceType nothing happens. Also I am running this in Google tag manager so I can't have a page refresh

```
   (function () {
    var sourceType;
    var query = parseQuery(window.location.search);
    var history = window.history
    delete query.sourceType 
    var search = stringifyQuery(query);
    if (window.location.search) {
      sourceType = window.location.search
          .substr(1)
          .split('&')
          .filter(function (i) {return ~i.indexOf('sourceType=')})
          .map(function (i) {return i.split('=')[1] })[0]
     history && history.replaceState && history.replaceState(history.state, null, window.location.pathname + search)
    }
  })()  

  function parseQuery (locationSearch) {
  if (typeof locationSearch !== 'string' || !locationSearch.length) {
    return {}
  }

  var query = {}
  locationSearch.substr(1).split('&').forEach(function (partStr) {
    var parts = partStr.split('=')
    var key = parts[0]
    var val = decodeURIComponent(parts[1])
    if (query.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var existingVal = query[key]
      if (existingVal instanceof Array) {
        existingVal.push(val)
      } else {
        query[key] = [existingVal, val]
      }
    } else {
      query[key] = val
    }
  })
  return query
}

function stringifyQuery (query) {
  if (!query) return ''

  return '?' + Object.keys(query).map(function (key) {
    var val = query[key]
    if (val instanceof Array) {
      return val.map(function (valPart) {
        return [key, encodeURIComponent(valPart)].join('=')
      }).join('&')
    } else {
      return [key, encodeURIComponent(val)].join('=')
    }
  }).join('&')
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you do but I think this should work? `window.location.search.replace(/sourceType=[^&]*/, "").replace("?&","?")`

Comment: [Query strings are harder than they seem](http://zzzzbov.com/blag/querystring-hell). Use a lib. [I wrote one that should cover most bases](https://github.com/zzzzBov/QueryStringJS), but there are other reasonable options.

Comment: How about using the "Exclude URL Query Parameters" in your View Settings in GA? That can effectively strip out the entered QSPs from your URL without any coding.

Answer (score 0):

Could not understand much from the above src that you have given. If you want to remove query string from a URL the following can help you

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
```

this line will split and give you an URL without query sting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this seems to work

so if my url was 
https://test.com/deal/141788/colored-tempered-glass-iphone-screen-protector?sourceType=by_content&somestring=true&moreparams=true

and I wanted it to look like 
https://test.com/deal/141788/colored-tempered-glass-iphone-screen-protector?somestring=true&moreparams=true

```
 function changeUrl()  {
      var sourceType;
      var query = parseQuery(window.location.search);
      var history = window.history
      delete query.sourceType
      var search = stringifyQuery(query);
      history && history.replaceState && history.replaceState(history.state, null, window.location.pathname + search)
      }


  function parseQuery(locationSearch) {
      if (typeof locationSearch !== 'string' || !locationSearch.length) {
          return {}
      }

      var query = {}
      locationSearch.substr(1).split('&').forEach(function(partStr) {
          var parts = partStr.split('=')
          var key = parts[0]
          var val = decodeURIComponent(parts[1])
          if (query.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              var existingVal = query[key]
              if (existingVal instanceof Array) {
                  existingVal.push(val)
              } else {
                  query[key] = [existingVal, val]
              }
          } else {
              query[key] = val
          }
      })
      return query
  }

  function stringifyQuery(query) {
      if (!query) return ''

      return '?' + Object.keys(query).map(function(key) {
          var val = query[key]
          if (val instanceof Array) {
              return val.map(function(valPart) {
                  return [key, encodeURIComponent(valPart)].join('=')
              }).join('&')
          } else {
              return [key, encodeURIComponent(val)].join('=')
          }
      }).join('&')
  }
```